# Event registration

Tags: 8, forms, webforms, rng

I am currently building a website in Drupal 8 for an organization. 
Below the basic page with information of an event I want to add an entry form to the event. 
There are multiple events on yearbase and every entry form is different. So there is not a standard form to place below the page.

What is the best way to go I have searched with current forms, [webforms](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform) and [RNG](https://www.drupal.org/project/rng).

Can someone help me out with this.